# Unit Testing Safe Apps with Safe Context

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm writing some unit tests for a react safe app. The `cra-template-safe-app` comes with one test out of the box:

```
test('renders learn loading screen', () => {
  render(<App />)
  const waitingHeading = screen.getByText(/Waiting for Safe/i)
  expect(waitingHeading).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

This test passes.

When I write tests for other components of my app, they fail because they are apparently testing against the "Waiting for Safe" page. Of course, the app is meant to be loaded in an iframe within gnosis-safe.io.

How do I load the context of a safe in the test environment?